# What query function to use to create a time column which changes its time with respect to diff time zone in which it gets open?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I want to know what query function should I use to create a Time column which changes its transactions timings when its open in different time zones? For instance if I am in PST zone where I created the time column which shows PST timing transactions, now if a person puts a query or create a report on this  time column in EST OR CST he/she should see transactions times from their respective time zones. Is there a way we can achieve this in Oracle 11g. I am still learning Oracle SQL. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged this for three different databases- MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle.  The text of your question appears to indicate that you are really just using Oracle.  Are the other tags a mistake?  Or are you trying to come up with an approach that works across all three database engines?

Comment: We using Oracle 11g, just wanted to know how are the approaches in others to gain knowledge.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006728

Answer (score 0):

Please see below a very basic snippet code which i think with modification from your perspective will suffice your requirement. Hope this helps.

```
WITH TM_TEMP AS
  ( SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE ZN FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT CAST(CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) at TIME zone T.ZN AS TIMESTAMP)
FROM TM_TEMP T;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Input : SYSTIMESTAMP  --> 04/01/2016 07:58:09 -04:00 [EST]
Output : 04/01/2016 17:28:55.546934   [IST]
```

So in this way you can set the timezone as per your session(locations) and get the reports generated.